# What does "I would think so" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

[From the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would)

> **would imagine, say, think, etc. (that)…** used to give opinions that you
>   are not certain about
>
> *I would imagine the job will take about two days.*
>
> *I'd say he was about fifty.*

Does it means you think so but you are not so sure?

Is it popular in everyday conversation?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't really have such a specific meaning.  For example: "Mr. Loria is about six feet tall, correct?" - "**I would say so.**"  In that case it just indicates agreement, not uncertainty.

Comment: And sometimes it indicates just the opposite, *strong* agreement!  For example, ["(Paul said) 'I was well compensated for what I did—' 'I would say so!' interjected Claudia."](https://books.google.com/books?id=vV2mBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA535&dq=%22I+would+say+so!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3wd7x48bRAhVD5SYKHcc3BtEQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20say%20so!%22&f=false)  You have to interpret it from context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary you quote is perfectly accurate; "I would think", etc., is used in situations where you are expressing an opinion without being too sure about it. The difference between these two sentences is one of nuance:

> I think he's about fifty.
>
> I would say he's about fifty.

The first suggests that you have some grounds for your opinion, and the second that you're more or less guessing. See [this earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160851/can-i-would-say-always-replace-i-think#160919) for a further discussion.

It should be noted that *you would think* doesn't mean the same thing at all. If I say:

> You would think that the bank could figure out a more secure way to allow customers to transfer funds between accounts.

what I'm actually saying is that the bank **has not** figured out a secure way to handle fund transfers, and that this is **unexpected**. Unlike *I would think*, which is in the nature of a guess, *you would think* states something contrary to fact.